# Can SPSS perform chi-square test on an existing contingency table?

Tags: spss, contingency-tables

I understand that SPSS can create a contingency table, and at the same time perform the chi-square test.

However, is it possible that when we already have the contingency table, to have SPSS do the chi-square test?

Comment: If you have the CTABLES license you may be able to do this test through that command. I can't find anything in the native descriptives/crosstabs that would allow you to do this. You could always calculate it yourself as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible in SPSS.

The data set must have all the counts in one column and the identifying information in two other columns.

The variable that contains the counts needs to be identified by choosing "Weight Cases" from the "Data" menu.

Click "Weight cases by frequency variable" and move over the variable containing the counts.

Then use "Crosstabs" to get the results.